# C# Selenium proxy option

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

Hello I have bought some residential proxies. However they require user:pass auth as well as the address:port.

I can't seem to authenticate it in Selenium C#.
This is my code for setting up the proxy settings:

```
options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://myusername:mypassword@proxyaddress:proxyport");
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It gives me an error on google page: ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES.
I am certain I have set it up wrong

Regards.

Comment: Which "residential proxies" did you buy? How are they configured? What is a "residential proxy"? I've never heard of this term before.

Comment: A residential proxy is a private IP proxy I guess you can say. It is not located in a datacenter like normal proxies. They are more expensive, and they are typically not identified by websites as "suspicious ip".

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Method with SendKeys("username") and ("password") and let it press Enter.